# what does <E> do exactly when writing a method using generics in java?

Tags: java, generics

Normally when we want to write a very basic method that prints out all elements in an array, it is like this:

```
public static void printArray(int[] array)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
        System.out.println( array[i] );
}
```

But when we want to use generics, it becomes:

```
public static <E> void printArray(E[] array)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
        System.out.println( array[i] );
}
```

The thing I don't understand (may be silly) is that the keyword "void" already represents the type of this method, then why exactly do we need "<E>" before it? It looks like the only thing it does is to inform me that it is going to use generics, nothing else. But we never needed to write "<String>" before "void" simply to inform me that it was going to use strings.

Comment: I assume it tells the compiler that `E` refers to a generic type, rather than one specified somewhere else.

Comment: Isn't it enough that it tells the compiler it's a generic and not a class called E?

Comment: Sometimes you want to restrict `E` e.g., `E extends Comparable` to tell the method that variables of type `E` can be compared with one another.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes, at least unless you want to restrict `E` one **could** probably avoid the use of such construct entirely (by for example assuming that any undefined type refers to a generic type). However that's not the choice the designers of Java did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following two methods:

```
public static <E> void doSomething1(E a){
    //do something
}

//warning : The type parameter Integer is hiding the type Integer
public static <Integer> void doSomething(Integer a){
    // here Integer is generic type and not the usual Integer. You can see the above warning given by the compiler.
    //do something
}
```

The first method uses the general convention naming of generics. Whereas the second one uses an unusual name. But one can be easily mislead thinking that the second is of Standard **Integer** class type but it is not. Here  is just like <E>. Try in Eclipse(or other IDE). You will get a warning which I have put as a java comment. Also you can try to see what operations are possible with `Integer a`. You will find that you can see only standard Object type methods available instead of numerical Integer.

**Conclusion**: To use generics, you need to mention using <> otherwise it will try to find that class type. Like say you did not mention <E> then it will say `"E cannot be resolved to a type"`. So you need to mention that it is generic by mentioning <E>.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think your answer is most straightforward and easiest to understand (at least by me).

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a type parameter in a method signature means it is a generic method.  The type variable you declare there can not only be used in the parameter list again, but also in the method implementation itself.

For example:

```
public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) {
    return p1.getKey().equals(p2.getKey()) &&
           p1.getValue().equals(p2.getValue());
}
```

This method takes two Pairs, and the type parameter restrictions ensure that they're of the same generic type so they can be compared.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand how what you said is related to my question, but I think @Sami Kuhmonen's comment makes sense. I only thought about that usually we dont add any thing before "void" but didn't think that it would become a problem if the compiler misunderstood the E to be some class I defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider 2 methods(I have changed the genric method name for easy reading)

```
public static void printArray(int[] array)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
            System.out.println( array[i] );
    }
    public static <E> void printArrayGeneric(E[] array)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
            System.out.println( array[i] );
    }
```

When you call `printArray` then you have to mandatory pass array of integers. In future if you want to have same functionality for other datatypes lets say for string or char then are you going to write separate methods for string and char,NO right?
so you can use generics here

```
public static <E> void printArrayGeneric(E[] array)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
            System.out.println( array[i] );
    }
```

In this method you can pass Array of Objects so this means it will accept String,Character,Integer ....
sample example

```
public static void printArray(int[] array)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
            System.out.println( array[i] );
    }
    public static <E> void printArrayGeneric(E[] array)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
            System.out.println( array[i] );
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] z={1,2};
        printArray(z);
        String[] s={"a","z"};
        printArrayGeneric(s);
        Character c[]={'c','v'};
        printArrayGeneric(c);
    }
```

**output**

```
1
2
a
z
c
v
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but I think you may misunderstood my question. I understood what generics does. I just felt a little bit strange about the inconsistency when declaring a method since we usually only have the type "void" and now we need to have "<E> void". But I think @Sami Kuhmonen's comment makes sense. I only thought about that usually we dont add any thing before "void" but didn't think that it would become a problem if the compiler misunderstood the E to be some class I defined elsewhere.